# Expecting EOF, found 'for' - Processing

Tags: java, sorting, processing

This is my first ever question, apologies for any mistakes I make while asking for help!

I am trying to sort the 5 most repeated words from a text file in Processing and I'm confused about this error I keep getting. I'm new to Java and after searching the internet, any changes I make are not appear to be helping. What do I need to do to amend to fix the issue?

Here is the code in question -

```
import java.util.Iterator;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMultiset;
import com.google.common.collect.Multiset;
import com.google.common.collect.Multisets;

void setup() {
    size(800, 480);
    smooth();

    String[] data = loadStrings("data/data.txt"); 

    ImmutableMultiset<String> myMultiset = ImmutableMultiset.copyOf(data);
    top = Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(myMultiset);
}

Iterator it = top.entrySet().iterator();

for (int i = 0; (i < 5) && it.hasNext(); i++) {
    Multiset.Entry entry = (Multiset.Entry) it.next();

    String word = (String) entry.getElement();
    int count = entry.getCount();

    System.out.println(word + " -> " + count);
}
```

Thank you kindly in advance for the help!!

Comment: In Java, everything has to be outside a class (except classes (and interfaces and enums and annotations, which are actually all types of classes)).

Comment: @immibis This is Processing, not straight Java. The only problem here is an extra curly brace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
top = Multisets.copyHighestCountFirst(myMultiset);
}
```

It seems like this brace here isn't right.

Do you intend to end your "setup" method here?
If so you can't have things like sysout and for's not in a method, as well as there being an extra brace at the end.

Try putting the rest of your code in a method like so:

```
void iteratorMethod(){
    Iterator it = top.entrySet().iterator();

    for (int i = 0; (i < 5) && it.hasNext(); i++) {
        Multiset.Entry entry = (Multiset.Entry) it.next();

        String word = (String) entry.getElement();
        int count = entry.getCount();

        System.out.println(word + " -> " + count);
    }
}
```

Note that you will have to call `iteratorMethod()` in the last line of your setup method (assuming that's what you want to do).

Comment: Yes I wanted to end the setup method there. Is it right to end it there? I don't know anything about sysout but I'll look it up.

Comment: I don't know much about processing but I still think you need to use methods instead of having code just lying around. Also `sysout` is just short for `System.out.println()`

Comment: Added example of what I mean by putting the code in a method

Answer (score 1):

I edited to fix your indentation, and you appear to have an extra brace on the last line. If you copied the for-loop from inside a function, and accidentally copied the function's closing brace, please show us the rest of the function.

Comment: You should comment this instead of creating an answer

Comment: @TameHog But just yesterday I saw a warning on the RPG Stack Exchange, "Please do not answer in comments".

Comment: The brace was really the only problem? In that case I guess it's alright

Comment: Thank you for fixing the indentation. I removed the extra brace and I'm still getting the same error - here is a screenshot - http://oi57.tinypic.com/viecyp.jpg

Comment: @paypay23 The first thing I notice is that you don't actually call `setup()`; I don't know much about Processing, so this might not be required. But even if it's not required, the variable `top`, which you use to define `it`, is probably (again, I don't know about Processing) local to `setup()`. [The Wikipedia article example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29#United_States_presidential_election_map) defines the necessary variables outside any function. It could also be that your executed code isn't in a function; try wrapping the last lines in one.

Comment: Thank you kindly, I shall do this.